# Density scale of Y axis mysteriously changed when X scale is transformed to log10

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a density plot of this variable (`n_fractions$av`) distributed on 130,000 observations:

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  25.00   29.33   32.95   51.77   39.66 8275.00
```

Then if I plot this

```
ggplot(n_fractions, aes(x=av)) + geom_density()
```

I get [image]

But If I transform the X scale to log10

```
ggplot(n_fractions, aes(x=av)) + geom_density() + scale_x_log10() + coord_trans(x="log10")
```

The Y scale changed to values I can't interpret

[image]

Shouldn't density sum to 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The density should integrate to 1, which still allows the point estimate of the density as some point to exceed 1.

However, the reason that the general shape of the density is changing is that `scale_x_log10()` and `coord_trans(x="log10")` do different things. In particular, the scale transformation (`scale_x_log10()`) happens before any statistics (such as density) are computed. So the density that is plotted in the second case is the density curve of `log10(av)`. The coordinate transformation (`coord_trans(x="log10")`) happens after the statistics are computed and only effects the positioning on the screen.

It seems that you only what the coordinate transformation and not the scale transformation.